# SET Date in Column A of type TIMESTAMP in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am running following DB2 query:

```
UPDATE Table
SET DATE(COLA) = '2017-03-31'
WHERE DATE(COLA) = '2017-03-29';
```

COLA is of type TIMESTAMP.

Sample Value:

```
COLA:
2017-03-29-00.00.00.000000
```

Expected Updated Value:

```
COLA:
2017-03-31-00.00.00.000000
```

When I am running above query, I am getting

> SQL Code SQLCODE = -104,ERROR:  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "(". SOME SYMBOLS THAT
>   MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: = .

Could anyone help me out for this scenario?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A function, such as `DATE()`, cannot be on the left side of an assignment. Well, not in SQL anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do it:

```
UPDATE Table
SET COLA = '2017-03-31-00.00.00.000000'
WHERE DATE(COLA) = '2017-03-29';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it out.

Comment: UPDATE Table
SET COLA = '2017-03-31-00.00.00.000000'
WHERE DATE(COLA) = '2017-03-29'; 

It's working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I believe your problem is in the `SET` portion.  Try this:

```
UPDATE Table
SET COLA = DATE('2017-03-31') -- TIMESTAMP ('2017-03-31-00.00.00.000000') 
WHERE DATE(COLA) = '2017-03-29';
```

You want to update the column, not update the result of a function performed on the column.

Comment: You can simply assign a `DATE` value to a `TIMESTAMP` column, and the time part will default to all zeroes: `...SET colA = '2017-03-29'...`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it out.

Comment: UPDATE Table
SET COLA = TIMESTAMP ('2017-03-31-00.00.00.000000') 
WHERE DATE(COLA) = '2017-03-29';  
It's working fine. Thank you!

Comment: Another Case: 
If the COLA is not allowded to hold duplicate value, Could you please suggest approach to update only DATE part of timestamp from "2017-03-29" to "2017-03-31" in a single query instead of running query for each row.
Example:Current Table Values:
COLA 
2017-03-29-00.00.00.100000
2017-03-29-00.00.00.200000
2017-03-29-00.00.00.300000
2017-03-29-00.00.00.400000
2017-03-29-00.00.00.500000
Expected Table Value:
2017-03-31-00.00.00.100000
2017-03-31-00.00.00.200000
2017-03-31-00.00.00.300000
2017-03-31-00.00.00.400000
2017-03-31-00.00.00.500000
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Manas - if this helped you consider marking it as the correct answer (check box under the rocker).  If you have another question, it'd be best to post it as a new question.

Comment: Okay. Thanks you! I will post it as another question.